# I am trying to get chapterdetails from model but i am redirecting to this url '/accounts/django'?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

my views.py

```
@login_required
@api_view(['GET'])

def ChapterNames(request, id):
    liveclass_id = models.LiveClass_details.objects.filter(id=id).first()
    chapter_names = liveclass_id.chapter_ids.all()
    serializer = serializers.chapterNames_serializer(chapter_names, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

models.py

```
class ChapterNames(models.Model):
    chapter_names = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.chapter_names

class LiveClass_details(models.Model):
    standard = models.ForeignKey(LiveClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chapter_ids = models.ManyToManyField(ChapterNames)
    chapter_details = models.TextField(default='')
    mentor_id = models.ForeignKey(Mentor, max_length=30, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    doubtClass = models.OneToOneField(DoubtClasses, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    isDraft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ratings = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    no_of_students_registered = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    no_of_students_attended = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'LiveClass_details'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.chapter_details
```

here chapternames are added as many to many field in Django, user authentication and all the apis are working fine and only this one is causing error

urls.py

```
path('liveclass/', views.LiveClassView.as_view(), name='liveclass'),
    path('liveclass/<int:id>', views.LiveClassViewId.as_view()),
    path('liveclass/<int:id>/chapter-names', views.ChapterNames),
```

I am trying to hit liveclass/id/chapter-names but it is redirecting me to `/accounts/login/?next=/liveclass/1/chapter-names` when i tried to  access it in postman but it is giving me fine results in rest framework api view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put decorator @login_required in front of your view so it will try to login befor accessing the view if you are not yet logged in

Comment: no i am logged in and sending a token in authorization header in postman but still it is showing error

Comment: First remove the decorator and see if it works ok without it. If yes, then continue to setup token authorization (strategy: debug one thing after the other)

Comment: Yes it working without login_required decorator but with with it is causing the same error and i unable to understand that while its working on rest why its not on postman?

Comment: Do you need anything else for looking into the issue, i am using class based views for liveclass/ and liveclass/id/ endpoint but functional view for liveclass/id/chapter-names endpoint, can that be causing errors

Comment: Error is resolved while converting into a class based component so can you explain like cant we mix class based and function views for a same extended endpoint

Comment: Your browser stores a cookie when you login ... you need to do the same with postman to also store a cookie there.